# TCP still transmit data after backend FIN, ACK

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpdump

I'm new to analyzing tcp dumps. :) . While I was analyzing this dump (tcp dump taken from a backend server which is fronted by a load balancer), in **No 163**, **FIN** is sent by the backend but after acknowledging, the client has again sent data to the backend (**No 165**). I'm trying to find the reason for this behavior. (why data is sent after the FIN) . Any reference documents related to this are highly appreciated.

Following is part of the TCP dump.

```
No  | Time       | Source         | Destination   |Protocol|Length |  Info

161 | 736.441401 |  client(lb)    | server        | TCP    | 66    | 1027 → 80 [ACK] Seq=66678 Ack=8874 Win=94208 Len=0 TSval=1811562159 TSecr=3735198525
162 | 746.434713 |  server        | client(lb)    | TCP    | 97    | 80 → 1027 [PSH, ACK] Seq=8874 Ack=66678 Win=162560 Len=31 TSval=3735208526 TSecr=1811562159
163 | 746.434746 |  server        | client(lb)    | TCP    | 66    | 80 → 1027 [FIN, ACK] Seq=8905 Ack=66678 Win=162560 Len=0 TSval=3735208526 TSecr=1811562159
164 | 746.441244 |  client(lb)    | server        | TCP    | 66    | 1027 → 80 [ACK] Seq=66678 Ack=8905 Win=94208 Len=0 TSval=1811564659 TSecr=3735208526
165 | 746.441494 |  client(lb)    | server        | TCP    | 4483  | 1027 → 80 [PSH, ACK] Seq=66678 Ack=8906 Win=94208 Len=4417 TSval=1811564659 TSecr=3735208526
166 | 746.441506 |  server        | client(lb)    | TCP    | 54    | 80 → 1027 [RST] Seq=8906 Win=0 Len=0
167 | 746.441558 |  client(lb)    | server        | TCP    | 66    | 1027 → 80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=71095 Ack=8906 Win=94208 Len=0 TSval=1811564659 TSecr=3735208526
168 | 746.441564 |  server        | client(lb)    | TCP    | 54    | 80 → 1027 [RST] Seq=8906 Win=0 Len=0
```

Thanks

Comment: FIN means that the peer has stopped *sending.* There is no implication that it has stopped *receiving.*

Comment: @user207421thanks. but shouldn't the client also stop sending when it recieves a FIN, ACK from the backend?

Comment: No, because 'there is no implication that it has stopped receiving'. I said that already.

Comment: The definition of FIN: **FIN:  No more data from sender** There is a full handshake that must be done to close a connection. FIN is simply telling the other TCP that the sender is done, not that the other TCP is done. This is detailed on page 23 of _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#page-23)_.